# How do I get iMessage to only send to mobile numbers and not everything on the contact card?

Tags: iphone, ios, email, contacts

I have read answers to similar questions and it does not answer it completely.  I do not get prompted to answer where I want to send the message.  It just automatically sends to phone, email, and mobile.  This is a serious problem since it is trying to send to landlines as well.